# understanding these slokas of the shiva gita

Tags: shiva, gita

There are only brief explanations for the lines of Shiva Gita, and unlike Swami prabhupada's work on Bhagwad Gita As it is, I haven't been able to find a similar work on Shiva Gita, hence I am having trouble understanding the following slokas:

> तासामत्रास्ति का हानिर्यया कुप्यन्ति देवताः ।
>
> पाराशर्योऽथ मामाह यत्पृष्टं शृणु वत्स तत् ॥ ८॥
>
> नित्याग्निहोत्रिणो विप्राः संति ये गृहमेधिनः ।
>
> त एव सर्वफलदाः सुराणां कामधेनवः ॥ ९॥
>
> भक्ष्यं भोज्यं च पेयं च यद्यदिष्टं सुपर्वणाम् ।
>
> अग्नौ हुतेन हविषा सत्सर्वं लभ्यते दिवि ॥ १०॥
>
> नान्यदस्ति सुरेशानामिष्टसिद्धिप्रदं दिवि ।
>
> दोग्ध्री धेनुर्यथा नीता दुःखदा गृहमेधिनाम् ॥ ११॥
>
> तथैव ज्ञानवान्विप्रो देवानां दुःखदो भवेत् ।
>
> त्रिदशास्तेन विघ्नन्ति प्रविष्टा विषयं नृणाम् ॥ १२॥
>
> ततो न जायते भक्तिः शिवे कस्यापि देहिनः ।
>
> तस्मादविदुषां नैव जायते शूलपाणिनः ॥ १३॥
>
> यथाकथंचिज्जातापि मध्ये विच्छिद्यते नृणाम् ।
>
> जातं वापि शिवज्ञानं न विश्वासं भजत्यलम् ॥ १४॥

It is the part where Suta Ji, asks vyas rishi why would gods get angry if you recite shiva gita to anyone(as I understand), the Hindi translation is [as given in this pdf](https://archive.org/details/SHIVAGITA). I couldn't really make any sense out of what was written in the corresponding slokas. If anyone would be kind enough to explain me what these slokas mean it would be really helpful.

Comment: Its explained in detail in Upanishads where Shiva Gita personified Brahman as Shiva. 'Brahman was this before; therefore it knew even the Ātma (soul, himself). I am Brahman, therefore it became all. And whoever among the gods had this enlightenment, also became That. It is the same with the sages, the same with men. Whoever knows the self as “I am Brahman,” becomes all this universe. Even the gods cannot prevail against him, for he becomes their Ātma. Now, if a man worships another god, thinking: “He is one and I am another,” he does not know. He is like an animal to the gods.

Comment: 'As many animals serve a man, so does each man serve the gods. Even if one animal is taken away, it causes anguish; how much more so when many are taken away? Therefore it is not pleasing to the gods that men should know this.'
— Brihadaranyaka Upanishad 1.4.10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Siva Gita propounds knowledge of the Supreme, and when knowledge of the Supreme is attained there remains nothing to be done. You may know this, so people attaining knowledge renounce material affairs, work, etc. and become *sannyasi*.

So Sutaji answers why giving the knowledge of Siva Gita causes anger in the gods. He explains that work of the Brahmanas like *agnihotra*, *havana*, etc. nourish the gods in heaven and it is like their *kamadehenu* (wish fulfilling cow). But when knowledge of the supreme is given to the Brahamanas they renounce their day to day *agnihotra* work and hence the gods lose their nourishment. So gods cause trouble for the Brahman through his wife, sons, and other material things. So many don't tread this path of knowledge as so many troubles are faced and even if some begin, they drop the pursue in the middle having faced the problems.

This is basically gist of those verses.

Comment: Welcome back! :) Really happy to see good users from old time back in action again. You may want to join [main chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15189/hinduism) too.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto Thank You :)

Comment: Propounds knowledge of the Supreme? He basicallys says to Rama that he IS the supreme. He also shows his roopram form to Rama.