# heaven exists without havan

Tags: scripture

With [link to my previous question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/40510/understanding-these-slokas-of-the-shiva-gita?noredirect=1#comment127285_40510) , it is verified that whatever is given in havan(yagyas etc) is what is the nourishment for heaven. But, in this day and age where the havans and yagyas are so minimal, I wonder if heaven is suffering from poverty and malnutrition. What do the sastras/vedas/scriptures say about this?

Comment: Souls in Indra's loka lives in abundance. Also, they have sex allday long. So no there is no poverty there.

Comment: please use slokas and scriptic evidence and also implicit lang which is not very slang -ish